# Issue with uniform size for images in html

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have the following code for showing images in my page (inside class="floating-box"):

```
<img style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; width: auto; height: auto;" ng-src="{{product.image}}"/>

.floating-box {
display: inline-block;
width: 300px;
height: 450px;
margin: 10px;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

Issue is I am not seeing uniform size for all images. Smaller images are not stretching. Any idea whats going on ?

Thanks.

Comment: `width: auto%` doesn't look right.

Comment: … and `auto` doesn't mean stretch.

Comment: I thought auto meant stretch as necessary ? @Quentin

Comment: `auto` is generally the CSS default.. adding it just unnecessary bloats markup.

Comment: @Ahsan, Did you check the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to be **maximum* 100% of it's original width and that height will adjust accordingly (stretch to keep original image ratio) you can use:

```
<img style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" src="" />
```

If you want the image to take 100% of the viewport (100% of the available space) and the height will also adjust accordingly (stretch to keep original image ratio) you can use:

```
<img style="width: 100%; height: auto;" src="" />
```

I really advise using classes for that, this way you don't need to re-write all the css inline for each image.

```css
img.responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
img.full-width {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img class="responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50/f00/fff" /><br />
<img class="full-width" src="http://dummyimage.com/150x50/0f0/fff" /><br />
<img class="responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/200x50/ff0/fff" /><br />
<img class="full-width" src="http://dummyimage.com/250x50/0ff/fff" /><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve uniform images on site, you can use the open source library bootstrap-spacer via NPM

```
npm install uniformimages
```

or you can visit the github page:

```
https://github.com/chigozieorunta/uniformimages
```

Here's an example of how this works using the "unim" class (you'd require jQuery for this):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <link href="uniformimages.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
      <script src="uniformimages.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <a href="product1.html">
                        <img src="image1.jpg" class="unim"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <a href="product2.html">
                        <img src="image2.jpg" class="unim"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <a href="product3.html">
                        <img src="image3.jpg" class="unim"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```